# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'

Tags: python-3.x, list, attributeerror

I have an error but I don't know why. Here is my code:

```
import itertools
word = 'stop'
#input('Word [ 2-5 letters recommended ] :').lower()
word = list(str(word))
anagrams = ["".join(perm) for perm in itertools.permutations(word)]
file = open('wordlist.txt', 'r')
lines = file.read().split('\n')
for n, i in enumerate(anagrams):
            if i not in lines:
                    anagrams[n] = '/'
for i in enumerate(anagrams):
    if '/' in anagrams:
        while anagrams.count('/') > 0:
            anagrams = anagrams.remove('/')

anagrams = '\n'.join(map(str,anagrams))
print(anagrams.strip(''))
```

And here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>
    while anagrams.count('/') > 0:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a read through **[mcve]**. It's not clear what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: My main goal is to get new words out of my original word. Ex : 'Stop' should give me `'pots','spot', etc.` I added the second _for loop_ to eliminate extra lines from the output. You could run my code without the 2nd for-loop to understand what I mean.

Comment: Excellent, can you please *edit & update your question* so other users know too?

Comment: Done! I edited the question

Comment: Please don't radically change your question, and if you do make changes, just remove the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured how to do it:

```
import itertools
word = input('Word [ 2-5 letters recommended ] :').lower()
word = list(str(word))
anagrams = ["".join(perm) for perm in itertools.permutations(word)]
file = open('wordlist.txt', 'r')
lines = file.read().split('\n')
for n, i in enumerate(anagrams):
            if i not in lines:
                    anagrams[n] = '/'
if str('/') in anagrams:
    anagrams = [x for x in anagrams if x != '/']

anagrams = '\n'.join(map(str,anagrams))
print(anagrams)
```

Input:

```
Word [ 2-5 letters recommended ] : stop
```

Output:

```
stop
spot
tops
ostp
opts
post
pots
```

Comment: Edit this answer, explain what was wrong Accept your answer. :)